# When using fullPage.js to create a "sliding page" effect: how do you get the sliding page to stop before a button bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get a fullPage.js slider to function properly for a particular design. It should slide up in [the same manner it does here](http://www.balenciaga.com/us). The only difference is, when it arrives at the top, I'd like the sliding page to stop before a button bar.

I've attached a series of graphics below to demonstrate visually what is happening. Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

> [image: g1] [image: g2] [image: g3]

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should post the code you have tried and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fullpage.js `paddingTop` option with the `height` of your menu.